A Small Challenge: How to Print the String "-e" Using Bash echo
I tried to print the string "-e" using echo
I tried
echo "" -e
but a space is printed before -e, the output is:
 -e
so I tried to remove the space
echo ""-e
and the output is empty new line
also I tried
echo '-e'
echo "-e"
echo \-e
echo "-"'e'
and the result is empty new line
how to deal it as a string and not as a option?

The reason that none of your attempt works is because all those quotings and escapes are handled by the shell, not echo. For all your attempts, echo sees the same single argument -e passed to it.
The usual convention is to use -- to separate options and other arguments. For example, grep -q ... would do a silent match while grep -- -q ... would match against the pattern -q. However, this does not work for echo either.
If this is intended as a challenge, one answer could be
echo -e '\x2de'

This makes use of the following rule in the documentation of echo:

\xHH      the eight-bit character whose value is HH (hexadecimal).  HH
can be one or two hex digits

However, this is very cryptic and should not be used in practice. The sane way to output the string "-e" is to use printf:
printf "%s\n" -e


I second the final paragraph. echo is a compatibility and consistency nightmare if the first argument starts with "-" and/or any argument contains backslash. For the sake of your sanity, use printf for anything complex or that might confuse echo. See "Why is printf better than echo?"

Per the bash documentation:

Starting Bash with the '--posix' command-line option or executing 'set -o posix' while Bash is running will cause Bash to conform more closely to the POSIX standard by changing the behavior to match that specified by POSIX in areas where the Bash default differs. [...]

When the 'xpg_echo' option is enabled, Bash does not attempt to interpret any arguments to 'echo' as options.  Each argument is displayed, after escape characters are converted.


set -o posix
shopt -s xpg_echo
echo -e


This disables a lot more than just recognizing -e as an argument, though.

@chepner easily fixed by a subshell (e.g. echo()(set -o posix; shopt -s xpg_echo; builtin echo "$@")) - but better to just use printf

If an empty space behind isn't a problem, this worked for me -
$: echo '-e '
-e

You can throw in other hackery like preceding or following it with an alert or a backspace, or some other nonprinting hack.
$: echo $'\b-e' # leading backspace
-e
$: echo $'-e\a' # trailing alert/bell
-e

But all of these still pollute your actual data output, which might well matter.
As already stated elsewhere, the best solution is to use printf, which should always be available.
If for some reason you should need other ways to do it, which seems unlikely... you could always do something like this -
$: echo '-eX'| tr -d X # have tr trim the X off the end
-e

or just
$: cat<<<-e # cat with a bash here-string
-e

I must admit I am having trouble seeing why this would ever be an issue unless it's literally an assignment to demonstrate the problem. Are you just trying to assign a variable? You certainly don't need echo for that.
But just use printf.

echo -e "\x27\x2d\x65\x27"

You might need to assign it on MS filesystem using io lib on disk
echo -e "\x1A\x0B\x27\x92\x30\x27\x94\x64\x24\x1B"

Press home to put caret position before enter or put it in a cmd/batch/bat/sh/bash or whatever.
Try "\u20BF".
